# "Unload Me" Makes an input box appear - VISUAL BASIC

Tags: input, box

I am a new programmer in visual basic and I have created a hangman game. For some reason when i unload the program after playing, it makes my input box appear. Please help.

here is the dropbox link with all my visual basic files

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5xjla19aqqxi4ze/AABOHnSOpyAMtXbbPlsVo_OSa?dl=0

When you lose the hangman game, it asks if you want to play again. If you click no, the input box appears and asks for another word. You must type in a word, AND THEN it finally unloads.

thanks for the help

THIS IS WRITTEN IN VB6

Comment: tried Application.Exit?

Comment: I get "variable not defined" try my code, if you get it to work, please help

Comment: oh, it's written in vb5?  I have no means of compiling this at the moment.

Comment: it's vb6 actually. sorry for not specifying